# When describing someone are virtues and character the same?

Tags: aristotle, society

Are virtues and character the same thing? 
If not how would they differ

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Virtues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72083/1787) ([like grace](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72251/1787)) are [accidental](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31614) [qualities](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35934) of the soul. They can be gained or loss, just like the redness of an apple can be gained or lost.

Characters are indelible marks (cf. [the *OED*'s etymology for "character"](https://oed.com/view/Entry/30639?rskey=UapbCx#eid9587547)).

Bernard Wuellner, S.J., gives these definition in his [*Dictionary of Scholastic Philosophy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4797) p. 323:

> **virtue, *n*. 1**. a good operative habit in man; an operative habit perfect­ ing rational powers so that they act according to the rule of reason; a human habit that makes its possessor good and his work good. The point of human control of the virtue should be noticed, as in the case of HABIT.

and p. 49:

> **character, *n*.** the habitual [moral vir­tues](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72083/1787) and vices of a person, founded on his dispositions and together dis­tinguishing his moral personality; in­tegration of a person's nature and nurture in his habits and the expres­sion of these in his living.

"Virtue" comes from *vir* (man) or *vis* (strength). *Character* means a stamp or mark.